# Python regex - substitute all occurrences of keyword not preceded by specific characters

Tags: python, regex

**Problem**
I'm trying to replace all occurrences of `keyword` not preceded by `#` or `[[` with `[[keyword]]`.

For instance, the strings

```
keyword
#keyword
some keyword
[[keyword]] keyword
```

would be replaced with

```
[[keyword]]
#keyword
some [[keyword]]
[[keyword]] [[keyword]]
```

**Attempt**
I've tried `^(?!#.*$)keyword` which does not work when `keyword` has at least one other word in front of it.

Removing the `^` however causes all occurrences of `keyword` to be replaced, including the ones directly after a pound sign and brackets.

**Question**
How can I replace **all** occurrences of `keyword` except when following a `#` or `[[`?

Comment: Use `r'(?<!\[\[)(?<!#)\bkeyword\b'` to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b(?<!\[\[)(?<!#)keyword\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ncaJp/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\[\[)` - no `[[` substring is allowed immediately on the left
- `(?<!#)` - no `#` char is allowed immediately on the left
- `keyword` - a string
- `\b` - word boundary.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/90OKy2):

```py
import re
text = "keyword\n#keyword\nsome keyword\n[[keyword]] keyword"
print( re.sub(r'\b(?<!\[\[)(?<!#)keyword\b', r'[[\g<0>]]', text) )
## => [[keyword]]
## => #keyword
## => some [[keyword]]
## => [[keyword]] [[keyword]]
```

Note the `[[\g<0>]]` replacement contains a backreference to the whole match, `\g<0>`. You may want to use `\1` if you add capturing parentheses around `keyword` in the regex pattern.

Comment: thank you for the answer. My problem space has expanded slightly: I'm trying to avoid substituting occurrences of `keyword` for lines that start with `http`. `^(?!http)\b(?<!\[\[)(?<!#)keyword\b` puts me in a position similar to the original question, where it manages to avoid lines starting with `http` but fails to replace lines with multiple occurrences of `keyword`. Any help on refining this regex is appreciated

Comment: @SimonCarlson `re.sub(r'(?m)^(http.*)|\b(?<!\[\[)(?<!#)keyword\b', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) or fr'[[{x.group()}]]', text)`